# Resource not available Apache Tomcat

Tags: html, eclipse, tomcat

I frequently use `apache tomcat` with Eclipse without any problems

Now I change my computer , following the traditionel steps to configure tomcat with eclipse

1) unzip tomcat folder

2) Eclipse->new Server

but it doesn't work even`http://localhost:8080`showing`ressource not available`

the port is correct

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Right-click</kbd> on Server . <kbd>Click</kbd> on Properties , under the General tab , <kbd>Click</kbd> on Switch Location , it should change **[workspace metadata]** to something else. Apply and OK . <kbd>Double click</kbd> on the Server , will open the Overview page . Under Server Locations , <kbd>click</kbd> on Use Tomcat installation . Save the settings and start the Server.

Comment: use Tomcat installation is desactivated

Comment: Remove the projects from the server and then follow the process and then add your project.

Comment: the problem is partially solved :I get the Tomcat welcome page

but when  I run my exemple I get the error resource not available